# Facebook Access Token is null when posting score to Facebook Leader through iPad

Tags: ios, facebook, ipad

I am using Facebook Leader to post score that is working fine in the iOS 7 when I use iPhone but it is giving null Access token when I use iPad with iOS 7.When I used older version iPad then also it was working fine.I am getting this issue only when I use iPad with iOS.

**Code Snippet:**

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:permissions defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {

           NSLog(@" access==%@",[FBSession activeSession].accessTokenData.accessToken);

            NSMutableDictionary* params =   [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:

                                          [FBSession activeSession].accessTokenData.accessToken,@"access_token",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",time], @"score",nil];

            [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/scores"

                                         parameters:params

                                         HTTPMethod:@"POST"

                                  completionHandler:

             ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

                 // Handle results

                 NSLog(@"result==%@ eror==%@",result,error);

             }];
        }];
```

**Error Message:**

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x16573530 {com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={

    body =     {

        error =         {

            code = 2500;

            message = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.";

            type = OAuthException;

        };

    };

    code = 400;

}, com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=400}
```

I am stuck here.please suggest some way out.Is anything wrong with my implementation.

Comment: does this log printing access token?

Comment: No,its printing null.

Comment: when you are opening the session where its taking you for auth? facebook app or safari?

Comment: That goes to safari..

Answer (score 0):

You should use `session` instead of `[FBSession activeSession]` because Currently in this Block method you are Quering access token form previous session i-e `[FBSession activeSession]` and not `session` that is returned from `[FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:^block` . Or At-least assign `[FBSession setActiveSession:session];` before you get accesstoken.